# How can I virtualize an ARM machine in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, arm

I'm interested in developing some programs that use OpenCV, but I want them to run on an ARM environment.

Can I virtualize the ARM under a Windows environment with VMWare or VirtualBox or something?

Comment: You simply can't virtualize an ARM if you're on PC, but you can emulate it :)

Comment: Virtualization is used to run a guest OS under a supervisor or host OS without the guest OS knowing that it doesn't have full control of the computer. The ARM is a processor (hardware), not an OS (software).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found this!

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/rpiqemuwindows/files/latest/download
```

It's an image with Raspberry Pi with QEMU. You only have to double click on run.bat and follow instructions.

Runs perfect.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: as others have said, this is an emulator, not hypervisor

Comment: The original asker made it clear in the rest of the q/a that they actually needed emulation on a non-ARM machine, rather than virtualization on an ARM machine, so this answer is rather useful.

Answer (score 12):

As pointed Geoffroy, you can't virtualize ARM, but you can emulate it.
You can try [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) - generic and open source machine emulator and virtualizer.

Comment: Plus one for Qemu :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this emulator from Microsoft - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5352

Comment: Depending on what OP want to do, he may quickly be limited with this emulator, as it is conceived to work with limited functionality.

Comment: This link used to point to "Microsoft Device Emulator 3.0", but it is unavailable since mid-2021. It had this description: *“This is the v3 release of the Device Emulator, that released with Visual Studio 2008. V3 updates the V2 emulator that released with Windows Mobile 6.”*